# what is the terminology of this form of equation $x^2 +1/x^2 + \sqrt{x}$

Tags: terminology

what is the terminology of this form of equation. It has only one variable, but with rational exponents, it can be positive, negative or fraction such as below:

$ax^2 +b/x^2 + c\sqrt{x} =0 $

I understand it is not a polynomial function. but what can I call it in proper math terminology? is it some kind of a one dimension ODE (Ordinary Differential Equations)?

is there any standard way to solve this type of function? how can I describe the complexity of this function? (like we describe polynomial with order).
Many thanks!

Answer (score 1):

It's fair to call it an *algebraic* equation, since it consists of algebraic expressions.  A standard approach toward solving it is to get rid of the square root symbol by setting $x=u^2$, which produces

$$au^4+{b\over u^4}+cu=0$$

and then clearing out the denominator to get a *polynomial* equation in $u$:

$$au^8+cu^5+b=0$$

There is no general formula for expressing the solutions $u$ in terms of $a$, $b$, and $c$, as there is for a quadratic equation; you can only solve it numerically (or sometimes exactly) for specific values of the coefficients.